# Using S3 for Django CMS Picture plugin storage

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, boto, django-cms, django-storage

I'm trying to deploy a Django CMS project to Heroku. Media will be served from S3 via Django Storages and Boto. Currently the only media consists of Django CMS Picture plugins (which use a standard ImageField) and Aldryn Blog posts (which use a FilerImageField and easy_thumbnails).

Adding an image to blog posts via Django Filer works great, but adding an image when creating a Django CMS Picture plugin fails with a 500 error:

> POST /en/admin/cms/page/edit-plugin/3/ HTTP/1.1
>   Host: 192.168.1.104:8000
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Content-Length: 72567
>   Cache-Control: max-age=0
>   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>   Origin: `http://192.168.1.104:8000`
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
>   Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryegTMPxZL74Wiukrg
>   Referer: `http://192.168.1.104:8000/en/admin/cms/page/edit-plugin/3/`
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
>   Cookie: django_language=en; sessionid=wj7ayeia7rwggpxecatspe7lw5i12345; csrftoken=Pf342snoku6cdoRD6b9FCtxfqVQ12345
>
> HTTP/1.0 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
>   Date: Sun, 13 Jul 2014 07:06:46 GMT
>   Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3
>   Content-Language: en
>   Expires: Sun, 13 Jul 2014 07:06:46 GMT
>   Vary: Cookie
>   Last-Modified: Sun, 13 Jul 2014 07:06:46 GMT
>   Cache-Control: max-age=0
>   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
>   Content-Type: text/html

The image is successfully uploaded to S3, and the plugin is created in the CMS but shows as `<Empty>`. The following are what I perceive to be the relevant settings:

```
'''
We use S3 as our media backend on Heroku, so set that up
'''
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'me'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'hunter2'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket'

'''
Adjust media URL to point directly to S3
'''
MEDIA_URL = 'http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/'

'''
Adjust thumbnail storage
'''
THUMBNAIL_DEFAULT_STORAGE = DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE
```

Also, I can programmatically create a Picture plugin and it works fine:

```
df = File(f)
p = Picture(language=u'en', plugin_type=u'PicturePlugin', level=0, lft=1, rght=2, tree_id=3, placeholder=ph)
p.image.save(name='test.png', content=df)
p.save()
```

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated, I'm stuck.

**Edit 1:** Thanks for the reply, mkoistinen, trying to get you more info but I'm honestly a little confused about how the pieces fit together so I just took screenshots.

Plugin creation form:
[image]

Form in error state for a split second (I've tried to click that "Share this traceback..." button without success):
[image]

The image was stored to S3 and a CMSPlugin was created (but not a Picture):
[image]

Response is empty, also doesn't appear to be any JavaScript errors:
[image]

**Edit 2:** This replacement plugin works fine, don't know how:

```
# djangocms_pic/cms_plugins.py

from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool

from models import Pic

class PicPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = Pic
    name = 'Pic'
    render_template = 'pic_plugin.html'

plugin_pool.register_plugin(PicPlugin)

# djangocms_pic/models.py

from django.db import models

from cms.models import CMSPlugin

class Pic(CMSPlugin):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = CMSPlugin.get_media_path)

# djangocms_pic/templates/pic_plugin.html

<img src="{{ instance.image.url }}" />
```

Comment: Can you obtain the stack trace? Here's what I'd do: in Chrome, perform the action while the Network tab of the Chrome Dev Tools window is open, then, once you get the error, you should find an AJAX request made that produced the error. Clicking that request, then clicking "Response" should reveal the full stack trace. If you can, post this to the IRC channel (via Gist, et al) so we can track this down.

Comment: Added some more info, mkoistinen. Is there any more info I can gather to help shed some light on this problem?

Comment: OK, the url that you are obfuscating. What was it?

Comment: Another image from S3 (from my programmatically-created Picture plugin), I just didn't feel super comfortable giving out my bucket name.

Comment: Had the same problem. you might see if this fixes it for you. https://github.com/divio/djangocms-picture/pull/5